# where did my GIS question go

Tags: bug

I posted a question, got two comments on the meta site, now I can't find my question and its responses.  Is there a problem with the meta site today and the "this post does not meet our quality standards is not informative

Comment: Do you mean this question? http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/profile-modification

Comment: Agreeing with Dan on this, there is some seems to be backend functions (questions, comments) that are out of sync today.

Comment: Me too 0 question 0 answers

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be about an issue that was only occurring on that day. 